# react-router examples huge-apps: syntax unrecognized by webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR in ./huge-apps/components/GlobalNav.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/yyangbian/workspace/react-router-examples/huge-apps/components/GlobalNav.js: Unexpected token (22:2)
  20 | 
  21 | styles.activeLink = {
> 22 |   ...styles.link,
     |   ^
  23 |   background: light,
  24 |   color: dark
  25 | }
```

Below is the dependencies installed locally:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

The webpack config file is the same as that in the git repository: [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/webpack.config.js)
Below is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the content of the file ./huge-apps/components/GlobalNav.js around line 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object rest spread syntax (which is the `...` you're using in the style object) is not included in the ES2015 Babel preset, as it's not part of the ES2015 spec (or any spec, so far). You need to either install the [object rest spread transform plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) or the [stage 2 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).